Is there an efficient way to compute the inverse of several symmetric matrices that share the same structure?
I have many symmetric matrices to be inverted. They all share the form
$A^\top D_{x_1} A$, $A^\top D_{x_2} A$, ... with $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$, $n>p$ and $D_x$ positive diagonal but with terms that differ for every matrix to be inverted.
I even have $D_x=\text{diag}(A u_x)$, $u_x\in \mathbb{R}^p$ and I can stack them in a matrix $U=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}u_{x_1} & u_{x_2} &\dots \end{array}\right)$ but I don't know if it can help to further increase the computation speed.
Edit: these inverse matrices will be used to compute $(A^\top D_{x} A)^{-1}A^\top v_y$ for several values of $v_y$ so it can be seen as the solution to the inverse problem $A^\top D_{x} Ab_{x,y}=A^\top v_y$. Since there are many $v_y$ to be used, I think it would be useful to compute the inverses, but the computations of $(A^\top D_{x} A)^{-1}A^\top$ are also relevant.

The first thing to clarify is what purpose the computed inverses will serve.  Most applications are better processed by solving linear systems rather than computing an inverse matrix.

You don't need to compute the inverse, you just need to compute a factorization of the matrices, Cholesky factorization in this case since they are positive (semi-)definite. You can then reuse the factorization as many times as you want to solve linear systems with different right-hand sides $A^Tv_y$.
I would not suggest you try using an iterative solver, since there are multiple right-hand sides involved.
These matrices all share the same sparsity pattern (assuming that $D_x$ does not have zeros on the diagonal). So you could potentially reuse the fill-reducing ordering (i.e. the permutation that reduces the fill-in in the Cholesky factor) and the symbolic factorization of your matrix (i.e. the sparsity pattern of the Cholesky factor), and only perform the numerical factorization (i.e. actually computing the values in the triangular factor).
This would not provide a big saving on average, since the numerical factorization is usually the most expensive operation. Also, being able to reuse the symbolic factorization depends largely on what factorization code you use and with which interface. Most codes allows you to do this, but using them through some high-level interface (like Python or Matlab) may not give you access to all the functionalities.

Thank you for your answer: I will start to use the Cholesky factorization whenever it is possible instead of matrix inverse. This is not clear for me how I could reuse the  fill-reducing ordering and the symbolic factorization of the matrices but I will dig it further. I am not sure if it could be of any use, but I see that there also exists a Cholesky decomposition of a tensor, and it might be applied to my collection of matrix.
(I am using R which is also a high-level interface.)
